# Android Date to C# long DateTime-Ticks

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, date, datetime

I have an Android App and a C# mvc Web API. I want to sent a Date (and some other data) with a HttpPOST from the Android App to the WebAPI.

Right now I use `long ticks = myDate.getTime();` in Android and `DateTime date = new DateTime(ticks);` in C#.

With the Date `2014-06-11 00:00:00` my ticks in Android is `1402459200000` and my DateTime in C# is `0001-01-02​T14:57:25 PM`

How to properly convert a `Date to long` and from `long to DateTime`, from Android to C#?

PS: I could send a `String date` in Android, then convert it to a `DateTime date` and convert that to `long ticks` in C#, but since I need a long C# for a method I can't change the parameters of, I would prefer to just send the correct `long` from Android directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` in Java doesn't have ticks - it has milliseconds. Additionally, the epoch for `Date` is the Unix epoch (1970-01-01) whereas the epoch for `DateTime` is 0001-01-01. You need to take both of these into account - as well as the fact that the epoch of `Date` is in UTC, whereas the epoch of `DateTime` varies depending on kind. You probably want something like:

```
private static readonly UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                 DateTimeKind.Utc);

...

long millis = ...;
DateTime dateFromJavaApp = UnixEpoch + Timespan.FromMilliseconds(millis);
```

Or you could use my [Noda Time library](http://nodatime.org) which makes this (and many other things) simpler:

```
long millis = ...;
Instant instant = Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(millis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it might be useful for other people coming across this question. I personally don't need it anymore, since this question is from 7.5+ years ago, and I don't even work with Android nor C# right now. ;) (Also, your suggested method was added in C# Framework v4.6, which is from mid-2015, so wasn't available yet at the time I posted this question. But because of that it's actually good your added your answer, since the accepted method above might be deprecated by now.)

Comment: I was aware of this. When I look for answers to my questions and later find better answers, I go back and add it to help others :) - so I didn't mean exactly you.